# Inserting row values into another table's column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I'm trying to implement an **undo** and **logging** feature for my project.

When a user deletes a row from a table with the **DELETE_ROW** procedure i select all values from that row and insert it into my row_history table by serializing row values as xml with **LOG_DELETED_ROW** procedure, then i delete row from its original table.

Serializing with built-in functions of Oracle was easy but i couldn't find a way to deserialize the rowdata and insert it back to own table.

**Is there any way to store that deleted row into another table and restore it when needed?**

**Delete Procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure DELETE_ROW(tableName varchar2, userId varchar2, columnName varchar2, columnValue number) is
begin
  log_deleted_row(tableName, userId, columnName, columnValue);
  execute immediate 'delete from ' || tableName || ' where ' || columnName || ' = ' || columnValue;
end DELETE_ROW;
```

**Logging Procedure:**

```
create or replace procedure LOG_DELETED_ROW(tableName varchar2, userId varchar2, columnName varchar2, columnValue number) is
tableId number;
begin
  SELECT ID into tableId FROM TABLES WHERE NAME = tableName;

execute immediate
  'INSERT INTO ROW_HISTORY(TABLE_ID,ROW_ID,ROW_DATA)
   SELECT 
   '|| tableId ||', 
   '|| columnValue ||',
   to_clob(
       DBMS_XMLGEN.getxmltype(
           ''SELECT * FROM ' || tableName || ' where ' || columnName || ' = ' || columnValue || '''
       ) 
   )FROM DUAL';

end LOG_DELETED_ROW;
```

**Row History Table:**

```
create table ROW_HISTORY
(
  ID       NUMBER not null,
  TABLE_ID NUMBER not null,
  ROW_ID   NUMBER not null,
  ROW_DATA CLOB not null
)
```

Comment: Why can't you use Triggers? A trigger on Delete to Log the rows being deleted. What are your criterias for a restore (from the log table)?

Comment: With or without triggers, my question is that how can i insert a row's values to another table? And when needed i want to fetch that row from log table and insert it to it's original table. I'm trying to find a way to serialize/deserialize a row.

Comment: why do you store xml as clob?

Comment: I stored it as xml so i can fetch that clob back, deserialize and insert back into own table. But that's my worst-case senario because i don't want to mess with serializing/deserializing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DBMS_XMLSAVE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlsav.htm) seems to be the thing you need.Here is a procedure which should do what you need to do.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_xml_data(p_table IN VARCHAR2, xml_data IN CLOB) IS
   t_context    DBMS_XMLSAVE.CTXTYPE;
   t_rows    NUMBER;
 BEGIN
   t_context := DBMS_XMLSAVE.NEWCONTEXT(p_table); 
   t_rows := DBMS_XMLSAVE.INSERTXML(t_context,xml_data); 
   DBMS_XMLSAVE.CLOSECONTEXT(t_context); 
 END;
 /
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) package here - it will allow you to reconstruct insert statement knowing table name and columns.

Another, more complicated, way would be to insantiate [LCR$_ROW_RECORD](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/t_lcr.htm) object and then run its EXECUTE member - it will perform actual insert.